# In Python, how should one exclude lines of a file that contain any of a list of patterns?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, list-comprehension, lines

I have a file from which I want to remove every line containing certain patterns. Let's say the patterns are as follows:

```
lineRemovalPatterns = [
    "!DOCTYPE html",
    "<html",
    "<head",
    "<meta",
    "<title",
    "<link rel>",
    "</head>",
    "<body>",
    "</body>",
    "</html>"
]
```

How should I loop over the file and keep only the lines that do not contain any of these patterns?

```
HTMLGitFileContent = ""
HTMLSVNFileName = "README_SVN.html"
# Loop over the lines of the HTML SVN file, building the resultant Git file
# content. If any of the line removal patterns are in a line, remove that
# line.
HTMLSVNFile = open(HTMLSVNFileName, "r")
for line in HTMLSVNFile:
    for lineRemovalPattern in lineRemovalPatterns:
        if lineRemovalPattern not in line:
            HTMLGitFileContent = HTMLGitFileContent + "\n" + line
            break
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to parse html?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to remove any lines containing certain tags. I have a Markdown file for documentation. This is converted to standalone HTML for display in a SVN repository web interface and the standalone HTML is then trimmed down for display in a Git repository web interface. For the SVN repository, the full HTML file is rendered; for the Git repository, the HTML is placed within an existing web page and then rendered. So, I'm removing certain tags (e.g. ```<body>```) in order to counter errors in the Git repository web rendering mechanism.

Comment: An HTML tag could span multiple lines.

Comment: In general, this is true. For my case, I have it set so that they're on individual lines. This is more about how to write list comprehensions than about HTML, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) instead of `lineRemovalPattern not in line` to exclude lines which contain the substrings you're removing.

I'd echo @doctorlove though, in that you may be better served by a real DOM parser. Don't go too far down this road!

Comment: [Karl Barker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1226028/karl-barker) Haha, yes, you're likely right. I'll tread carefully!

Answer (score 0):

The following approach uses the negation of the return value of the function `any` applied to a list comprehension involving the current line and the list of patterns:

```
# Create a variable for resultant Git file content.
HTMLGitFileContent = ""
HTMLSVNFileName = "README_SVN.html"
HTMLGitFileName = "README.html"
# Loop over the lines of the HTML SVN file, building the resultant Git file
# content. If any of the line removal patterns are in a line, remove that
# line.
HTMLSVNFile = open(HTMLSVNFileName, "r")
for line in HTMLSVNFile:
    if not any(pattern in line for pattern in lineRemovalPatterns):
        HTMLGitFileContent = HTMLGitFileContent + line
HTMLGitFile = open(HTMLGitFileName, "w")
HTMLGitFile.write(HTMLGitFileContent)
```